# ObjectMapper can see subclass fields from superclass

Tags: java, json, jackson

I realized ObjectMapper's `writeValueAsString` method takes an `Object` type as a parameter. But it is able to produce correct JSON from underlying class object(which is a subclass of `Object class`). Normally, Java compiler wouldn't be able to access fields of a subclass from a superclass. How does ObjectMapper do it?

Comment: Probably by using reflection.

Comment: Via Reflection? Object.getClass returns subclass... So you can iterate fields